# Autodesk Forge Svf2 model not clearing memory after calling viewer finish()

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When loading 3d model using the svf2 format and switching to another model by calling viewer finish() and then reloading the new svf2 , the memory requires some idle time to be cleared specially when using big models.
I tried the same model in svf the memory is purged faster when calling finish.
Please any ideas

- I tried to wait and after 15+ min the memory is cleared.
- I tried the svf format the memory is cleared after calling finish

expecting to know if there is any function to clear svf2 memory quickly.

or am i missing or doing something wrong ?

Comment: how did you check memory is cleared in svf

Comment: i watched the memory usage consumption for the browser from the task manager

Comment: What was the size of the file that took 15 minutes to clear

Comment: To monitor memory usage consumption, it would be best to watch in browser developer tools under the Memory tab. I'm noticing a delay in clearing memory in SVF1 as well, can you please check in the browser developer tools Memory tab and please let me know the numbers again?